# Creating Connection Pools in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, connection-pooling

I'm trying to create a connection pool in glassfish. I've done this a million times so the 'how-to' is not the issue.

After I filled out all the info that the form needs to create the connection pool and I hit 'create/finish' then the screen just reloads and takes me back to the home screen without creating the connection pool.

This is super frustrating! (Aaaargh!!!) . I've tried multiple times to restart the application server but it doesn't work. Any tips on what I can do to fix this? Maybe there's a manual way to add a connection pool by editing some XML file or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be kind to your fellow developers... files an issue in the GlassFish JIRA (http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH) and provide the info the assigned engineer requests so this can be tracked and resolved... for the benefit of all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The configuration is stored as a `domain.xml` file (`.../<yourDomain>/config/domain.xml`) and you can edit this file manually (preferably while app server is down).

Look for:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool name="yourDS" ...>
  <description>...</description>
  <property name="DatabaseName" value="..."/>
  <property name="Password" value="..."/>
  <property name="User" value="..."/>
  <property name="ServerName" value="localhost"/>
  <property name="PortNumber" value="3306"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Comment: Notice in domain xml if you want an empty password you put empty, not the double parentheses () as in the GF admin console. So you put <property description="password" name="Password" value=""></property>

Answer (score 9):

Edit the `xml` as per jeha's answer, or use a command like this

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname    com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource --restype    javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource --property "User=myUser:Password=myPassword:URL=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost/dbname" myConnPoolName
asadmin create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid myConnPoolName jdbc/myConnPoolName
```

If the admin console crashes, it might be due to the browser's language if it's different from English.

Answer (score 1):

This plays nicely for Oracle and Glassfish 3, just replace your specfic bits as needed

```
create-jdbc-connection-pool --restype=javax.sql.DataSource --datasourceclassname=oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource --property=user=<USER>:password=<PWD>:url=<YOUR_SERVER>\\:<PORT>\\:<SID> <DataSourceName>
```

Note the double slashes to escape the embedded colons.